# ESP32 (clone) Wemos Mini : 5V on VCC won't boot ... except if USB plugged in

Tags: esp32, 5v, vcc

I try to power up an ESP32 Wemos Mini (clone) through the VCC pin ... but it d not boot.

Surprisingly, if I connect an USB cable onto the Wemos mini USB connector ( and not connected at the other end, so no power supplied) it boot/works as expected ...

There is something I don't understand ... help and advice appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have some unknown clone of some device. If it does not have a manual or schematics or website or anything, we can't help.

Comment: Hi, no much more to add ... with VCC only, the board don't boot. When USB pluggend (only one end, no power), the board boots.
It seems a capacitor is involved somewhere : if I unplug the USB cable and re-connect VCC - power supply quickly (1 minute delay) the board boots